# How to loop over a Geometry column data in MySQL / PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgis, multilinestring

I have a column named `schedule` with data type `MULTILINESTRING`.
Almost cases, this column contains any 1 `LINESTRING`, so I fetch data easily by script

```
ST_GeometryN(schedule, 1)
```

and then I check conditions from fetched data.

But if this column contains one more `LINESTRING`, I need to loop over it to check.

What is the best way to do?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is it mysql or postgresql ?

Comment: Its for both bro

Answer (score 0):

**PostgreSQL (PostGIS)**

The function you're looking for is **[ST_NumGeometries](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumGeometries.html)**.

Based on the following table structure:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tb (id INT, schedule GEOMETRY);
```

Containing the following records:

```
INSERT INTO tb 
VALUES (1,ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('MULTILINESTRING ((10 10, 20 20, 10 40),(40 40, 30 30, 40 20, 30 10))'));
INSERT INTO tb 
VALUES (2,ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)'));
```

Iterate over the geometries using something like (quick and dirty):

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
  i INT DEFAULT 0; 
  j RECORD;
  dim INT DEFAULT 0;  
BEGIN
    FOR j IN SELECT * FROM tb LOOP
      SELECT ST_NumGeometries(j.schedule) INTO dim;
      WHILE i < dim LOOP
        i:=i+1;  
        RAISE NOTICE 'Do something with geometry % : %',j.id,(SELECT ST_ASTEXT(ST_GeometryN(j.schedule, i)) );          
      END LOOP;
      i:=0;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Output:

```
Do something with geometry 1 : LINESTRING(10 10,20 20,10 40)
Do something with geometry 1 : LINESTRING(40 40,30 30,40 20,30 10)
Do something with geometry 2 : LINESTRING(30 10,10 30,40 40)
```

---

Depending on what you need to do with these linestrings, I would suggest put this code into a **[function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html)**.